# can't call addSQLmethod in my main method

Tags: c#, sqlite

Hi Currently I am trying to build a table using SQLite however I cannot see to call my method that I created into my main method. I don't really understand why I can't call it in the main method.  I have tried to make my method addSQL private and public however although I know this doesn't really affect much I still tried.  Currently it won't pick my my method at all when I try to call it in main method. Also in my addSQL method I get an error when using insertCommand saying it doesnt exist in current context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SQLserver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=test.db; Version=3;");
            myConnection.Open();
            /// If this is not the first time the program has run, 
            /// the table 'cars' will already exist, so we will remove it
            SQLiteCommand tableDropCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            tableDropCommand.CommandText = "drop table Records";
            try
            {
                tableDropCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex) // We expect this if the table is not present
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table 'Records' does  not exist");
            }

            /// Now create a table called 'records'
            SQLiteCommand tableCreateCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            tableCreateCommand.CommandText = "create table Records (ID int, FuelType varchar(10), Price float (50), TankVolume int)";
            tableCreateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            /// Now insert some data.
            /// First, create a generalised insert command
            SQLiteCommand insertCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
            insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into cars (ID, FuelType, Price, TankVolumes) values (@id, @fueltype, @price, @volume)";
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id"));
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@fueltype"));
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@price"));
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@volume"));
            addSQL();
        }

        public void addSQL()
        {
           /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
           insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;
           insertCommand.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = "Ford";
           insertCommand.Parameters["@model"].Value = "Focus";
           insertCommand.Parameters["@seats"].Value = 5;
           insertCommand.Parameters["@doors"].Value = 5;
           insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }

    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: sorry my code is quite misleading...Currently it won't pick my my method at all when I try to call it in main method. Also in my addSQL method I get an error when using insertCommand saying it doesnt exist in current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addSQL` is an instance method, you can't call instance method from Static method directly. Either make `addSql` as static, or call it through instance of the class.

The **other problem** in your code is that `insertCommand` is not visible to the method. You can pass that as parameter to your method, otherwise it will not compile. So you can define your method as static and like:

```
public static void addSQL(SQLiteCommand insertCommand)
{
   /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
   insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;
   insertCommand.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = "Ford";
   insertCommand.Parameters["@model"].Value = "Focus";
   insertCommand.Parameters["@seats"].Value = 5;
   insertCommand.Parameters["@doors"].Value = 5;
   insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

addSql is not static, so to call that method as it is, you need an instance of class Program. To get around your problem just make addSql a static method.

```
    public static void addSQL()
    {
       /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
       insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;
       insertCommand.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = "Ford";
       insertCommand.Parameters["@model"].Value = "Focus";
       insertCommand.Parameters["@seats"].Value = 5;
       insertCommand.Parameters["@doors"].Value = 5;
       insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make addSql() Method as static

Answer (score 0):

Make your `addSQL` method static and take a `SQLiteCommand` parameter:

```
...
    addSQL(insertCommand);
}

public static void addSQL(SQLiteCommand insertCommand)
{
   /// Now, set the values for the insert command and add two records
   insertCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = 1;
   insertCommand.Parameters["@manufacturer"].Value = "Ford";
   insertCommand.Parameters["@model"].Value = "Focus";
   insertCommand.Parameters["@seats"].Value = 5;
   insertCommand.Parameters["@doors"].Value = 5;
   insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but SqlLiteCommand is highlighted in red saying namespace name could not be found

Comment: @DorkMonstuh Sorry.  Typo.  Fixed it.